# Python Parsing HTML Assistance

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm working on a side project to scrape some Crossfit Workouts from a website that posts daily workouts.

When I parse the content, the output is truncated (it doesn't return the entire workout description).

I tried using lxml and BeautifulSoup and got the same result.

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.crossfitinvictus.com/wod/august-8-2023-performance')
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
description=tree.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content')
print(description)
```

This is the output:

['Warm-up Two sets of: Assault Bike x 2 minutes Plank x 1 minute Bottom Squat KB Goblet Hold x 30 seconds Two sets of: Banded Face Pull x 20 reps Air Squat x 10 reps A. Every 2 minutes, for 12 minutes (6 sets): Front Squat *Set 1 – 3 reps @ 70% *Set 2…']

There are additional lines after the Set 2... text which are missing.

Is this a website server issue?

I tried through VS Code and JupyterNotebook editors.

Comment: What you want is in `div.entry-content`. You're just scraping a brief description from the metadata of the page. Right click on the list and select "inspect". This will bring you directly to it's spot in the source. You can see exactly how the data is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get full content you can get text from tag with `class="entry-content"`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.crossfitinvictus.com/wod/august-8-2023-performance/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one(".entry-content").get_text(separator="\n", strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Warm-up
Two sets of:
Assault Bike x 2 minutes
Plank x 1 minute
Bottom Squat KB Goblet Hold

...all the way to:

Barbell should start from the ground.
Compare results to April 4, 2023.
```

Comment: Thanks.  I learn something new everyday!